# Store array into array of array

Tags: php

Im generating [Chart4PHP](http://www.chartphp.com/docs/).
In sample it takes data like this

```
$p->data = array(array(array("2010/10",-48),array("2011/01",238),array("2011/02",395)));
```

I have array "rows" constructed of row[date][units].
Im storing it in this way:

```
$rows = array();
for(...)
{
$row[date] = $mydate;
$row[units]= $myunits;
$rows[]=$row;
}
```

What I should make additionally to be able to use it as $p->data = $rows;

Comment: `$rows['data'][] = $row`?

Comment: Are you sure you need a 3-dimensional array, not 2-dimensional? Do you have a link to the Chart4PHP documentation?

Comment: Found it at http://www.chartphp.com/docs/

Comment: http://www.chartphp.com/demo/ Line chart sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the extra array container, call `array()` with the rows array as the argument.

```
$data = array(array('date' => "2010/10", 'units' => -48),
              array('date' => "2011/01", 'units' => 238),
              array('date' => "2011/02", 'units' => 395));

foreach ($data as $d) {
    $mydate = $d['date'];
    $myunits = $d['units'];
    $rows[] = array($mydate, $myunits);
}
$p->data = array($rows);
```

Comment: in this way it takes only $mydate to show in the output, it wont read second value of array. If i change  $rows[] = array($myunits, $mydate); it shows units (so data is OK).

Comment: My code should create the exact result that you asked for in the question.